# How to set .htaccess in order to block certain URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, web

here's my website organization:
[image]

index.php includes header, home, and footer files:
[image]

How should I set .htaccess so that MyWebSite/ is the only allowed URL?

Comment: what version of apache are you using?

Comment: @Panama Jack I don't know, the one provided by the last version of MAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it this way. Block all php files except from `localhost` or `server IP address`.

**For Apache < 2.4**

```
<Files ~ "\.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files "index.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

**For Apache >= 2.4**

```
<Files ~ "\.php">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files "index.php">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

Mamp should be using Apache 2.4 so the 2nd example should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it let me know that my apache is < 2.4 as well

Comment: No problem glad it worked out. And technically this isn't a duplicate to the that other question as it doesn't really provide a relevant answer.

Comment: indeed, my question was more specific, either was your answer. It will help people with the same trouble if both threads are linked.